# How can i open the dropdown in the div without scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-select

I have a DIV with a constant width and there's a table with 5 columns and two rows. Within each cell is a DropDown.

I want to scroll horizontally but I don't want open DropDown in DIV with scrolling and I want to get out of the div.

How to do it?

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    noneResultsText: 'موردی یافت نشد'
});
```

```css
#a1{
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow-y:auto;
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 
<div id="a1">
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>hi</th>
    <th>bye</th>
    <th>hi</th>
    <th>bye</th>
    <th>hi</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>
   <select class="selectpicker">
<option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option>
</select>
</td>
    <td>
    <select class="selectpicker">
<option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option>
</select>
</td>
    <td>
    <select class="selectpicker">
<option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option>
</select></td>
    <td>
    <select class="selectpicker">
<option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option>
</select>
</td>
    <td>
    <select class="selectpicker">
<option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>





<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have absolutly no idea what you want!

Comment: @eisbehr if you open the select it gets clipped because the parent `div` is set to `overflow: scroll`

Comment: I think OP's want list in popup window.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/